# Finding Common Values While Looping Over Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a situation where I need to compare and find common values over two arrays. I am clear on how to do it with one, but not sure how to do it in this case.

My first array looks like this:

```
[ { kind: 'E',
    path: [ 'short_name' ],
    lhs: 'testing',
    rhs: 'testing1' },
  { kind: 'E',
    path: [ 'agent_name' ],
    lhs: 'testing',
    rhs: 'testing2' } ]
```

The array above represents information pertaining to what changed on a document.

My second array looks like this:

```
[ { lhs: 'legacyId', rhs: 'id_number' },
  { lhs: 'name.short', rhs: 'short_name' },
  { lhs: 'name.long', rhs: 'agent_name' },
  { lhs: 'gender', rhs: 'gender' },
  { lhs: 'dob', rhs: 'date_of_birth' } ]
```

What I need to do is loop through and find common values for "path" in the first array's elements, and the second array's "rhs" value.

So according to my examples here, I should end up with these values being found: `short_name` and `agent_name`.

How could I write a loop to do this over the two arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `reduce` the 1st array and use a `forEach` loop over the second array to see if each of the values are equal, then push the value to the accumulator:

```js
const arr1 = [{ kind: 'E', path: [ 'short_name' ], lhs: 'testing', rhs: 'testing1' }, { kind: 'E', path: [ 'agent_name' ], lhs: 'testing', rhs: 'testing2' }]
const arr2 = [{ lhs: 'legacyId', rhs: 'id_number' }, { lhs: 'name.short', rhs: 'short_name' }, { lhs: 'name.long', rhs: 'agent_name' }, { lhs: 'gender', rhs: 'gender' }, { lhs: 'dob', rhs: 'date_of_birth' }]

const common = arr1.reduce((a, o1) => {
  const match = arr2.find(o2 => o1.path[0] === o2.rhs)
  match && a.push(match.rhs)
  return a
}, [])

console.log(common)
```

If you truly wanted to, you could write this in one line with a find instead of a second reduce:

```js
const a = [{ kind: 'E', path: [ 'short_name' ], lhs: 'testing', rhs: 'testing1' }, { kind: 'E', path: [ 'agent_name' ], lhs: 'testing', rhs: 'testing2' }]
const b = [{ lhs: 'legacyId', rhs: 'id_number' }, { lhs: 'name.short', rhs: 'short_name' }, { lhs: 'name.long', rhs: 'agent_name' }, { lhs: 'gender', rhs: 'gender' }, { lhs: 'dob', rhs: 'date_of_birth' }]

const common = a.reduce((a, o1) => (a.push(b.find(o2 => o1.path[0] === o2.rhs).rhs), a), [])

console.log(common)
```

Or, for a more performant solution <sub>;)</sub> You could use a set:

```js
const a = [{ kind: 'E', path: [ 'short_name' ], lhs: 'testing', rhs: 'testing1' }, { kind: 'E', path: [ 'agent_name' ], lhs: 'testing', rhs: 'testing2' }]
const b = [{ lhs: 'legacyId', rhs: 'id_number' }, { lhs: 'name.short', rhs: 'short_name' }, { lhs: 'name.long', rhs: 'agent_name' }, { lhs: 'gender', rhs: 'gender' }, { lhs: 'dob', rhs: 'date_of_birth' }]
var commonValues = []
var set = new Set([])

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
  const value = a[i].path[0]
  if (!set.has(value)) set.add(value)
}
for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  const val = b[i].rhs
  if (set.has(val)) commonValues.push(val)
}

console.log(commonValues)
```

Comment: I really like how succinct this solution is.

Comment: @Ademo definitely the most readable solution, but keep in mind that the time complexity is O(n^2) when using nested loops (both reduce and .forEach are loops) so if your data is large this solution will run pretty slowly.

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted? Please explain why so I can fix my code :)

Comment: This solution is O(n^2) time, it's just not the right way to solve this problem. As soon as this application/ page/ whatever gets a significant amount of data this is going to slow to a crawl or even have timeout errors.

Comment: @CalIrvine It works? It was accepted? It has solved the problem. OP didn't ask for a performance-first solution, otherwise I would've tailored my answer accordingly. I could pick on other answers because it wasn't written in one line, but that wasn't what was asked :P

Comment: @Kobe It works at this scale, but it won't work at large scale. As a developer you should try to alway keep all use cases in mind. A solution that works as data grows is crucial for any real world application, so we should all strive to do it right the first time, not down the road as it becomes necessary. Make your solution O(n) and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @CalIrvine It will work at a large scale, maybe not as fast as you would like it, but computers are very, very fast these days :) It's a shame you don't see that it doesn't matter. Sure, I should strive to make it as efficient as possible, which I did under the circumstances of using reduce, but I made a readable and short version. If this data was to grow, a database and query would be the solution here, not a script.

Comment: @CalIrvine I know enough about time complexity to realise JavaScript isn't the solution when data grows :)

Comment: @Kobe https://jsperf.com/spread-vs-return/5 with console.log removed and data increased some more. As data gets larger, my solutions lead will increase, as quadratic time grows exponentially but linear time grows linearly.

Comment: None of these will work if `path` has more than one element. Also problematic if `path` is empty array

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simply `for` inside a `for`...

This is the most simple (maybe not the most performatic) way you can do that, getting the value from first array, then looping the second one. If a value is found, then push it to another array (`results`) and break the second loop (there's no need to still running if a value already match).

```js
var a = [ { kind: 'E',
    path: [ 'short_name' ],
    lhs: 'testing',
    rhs: 'testing1' },
  { kind: 'E',
    path: [ 'agent_name' ],
    lhs: 'testing',
    rhs: 'testing2' } ]


var b =[ { lhs: 'legacyId', rhs: 'id_number' },
  { lhs: 'name.short', rhs: 'short_name' },
  { lhs: 'name.long', rhs: 'agent_name' },
  { lhs: 'gender', rhs: 'gender' },
  { lhs: 'dob', rhs: 'date_of_birth' } ]
  
var results = [];  
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  var path = a[i].path;
  
  for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
    var rhs = b[j].rhs;
    if (rhs == path){
      results.push(b[j].rhs)
      break;
    }
    
  }
}

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in O(n^2) time by nesting a loop and searching through the second loop for every value of the first loop, or you can use a hashmap to do it in O(n) time. In JavaScript we use objects for that because their values can be accessed in O(1) time.

Example:

```
const array1 = [
  { kind: "E", path: ["short_name"], lhs: "testing", rhs: "testing1" },
  { kind: "E", path: ["agent_name"], lhs: "testing", rhs: "testing2" }
];

const array2 = [
  { lhs: "legacyId", rhs: "id_number" },
  { lhs: "name.short", rhs: "short_name" },
  { lhs: "name.long", rhs: "agent_name" },
  { lhs: "gender", rhs: "gender" },
  { lhs: "dob", rhs: "date_of_birth" }
];

const hashMap = {};
const commonValues = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  const currentValue = array1[i].path[0];
  hashMap[currentValue] = true;
}

for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
  const currentValue = array2[i].rhs;
  if (hashMap[currentValue]) commonValues.push(currentValue);
}

//now commonValues contains all of the common between them. You may want to filter out duplicate matches, depends on your use case.
```

While it may seem like a lot more code, the time complexity savings are huge as your data gets arbitrarily large by doing it this way. Imagine your data is 100 items long, already an O(n^2) solution would require 10,000 passes to find all of the matches. Conversely with the above solution, it would require 200 passes. These savings in time add up quickly as your data gets larger.

Comment: I would like you to see this  https://jsperf.com/spread-vs-return I tried testing my two methods with a bigger data set, turns out your solution is actually 99% slower :/ If you could make your solution 99% faster, I'll remove my downvote :)

Comment: @Kobe the dramatic difference is because I forgot to remove a console.log from one of the loops. I've edited my answer and it's gone now.

Comment: @Kobe Your answer keeps the lead with the data provided, but I then tripled the size of one array and my answer took the lead.

Comment: @Kobe https://jsperf.com/spread-vs-return/5 May I have that downvote removed, as promised? :D

Comment: Last time I checked, that's more than triple the size :P True my answer doesn't handle duplicates well, but then using that size of data i would use a db query :) Sure, ill remove it, your answer is better :)

Comment: @Kobe I copy and pasted a couple times, I didn't count. I was being lazy hahaha. I agree that JavaScript is not the correct solution for this kind of scenario, but sometimes our hands are tied on what we are able to use. It's good to get in the practice of trying to reduce time complexity everywhere we can. That's how you write code that ages well. And sometimes that means returning to the trusty for loop.

Comment: Check my answer now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196379/discussion-between-cal-irvine-and-kobe).

Answer (score 1):

Make a `Set` out of the `rhs` values in second array and reduce first array and filter paths by checking against the set

```js
const arr1= [ { kind: 'E',
    path: [ 'short_name' ],
    lhs: 'testing',
    rhs: 'testing1' },
  { kind: 'E',
    path: [ 'agent_name' ],
    lhs: 'testing',
    rhs: 'testing2' } ],
    
    arr2= [ { lhs: 'legacyId', rhs: 'id_number' },
  { lhs: 'name.short', rhs: 'short_name' },
  { lhs: 'name.long', rhs: 'agent_name' },
  { lhs: 'gender', rhs: 'gender' },
  { lhs: 'dob', rhs: 'date_of_birth' } ],
  
  arr2Set = new Set(arr2.map(({rhs}) => rhs)),
  matches = arr1.reduce((a,{path}) =>[...a, ...path.filter(p => arr2Set.has(p))],[]);
  
  
  console.log(matches)
```

Comment: Spreading out a here heavily reduces speed. It would be best to push the values from the filter to a and then return a.